# why the string is getting altered after strcat()?

Tags: c, string, output

this is the source code

```
int main()
{
    char str[]="dance";
    char str1[]="hello";
    char str2[]="abcd";
    strcat(str1,str2);
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

#### output- `bcd`

why `str` is changed after `strcat(str1,str2);`

Comment: try to print the size of each array, you should get the answer by yourself

Comment: becuase there are 4 char (single byte each) allocated to str1, and 4 for str2. so you are overwriting the bytes of str1

Comment: My understanding is that all three strings should be read-only, as they're pointing to fixed strings, so it may not be well-defined what happens when you try writing to these arrays. Plus, str1 would have to be 4 bytes longer to fit the concatenated string. Why str would change is a puzzler.

Comment: The three pointers (str, str1, str2) themselves should be read-write, but they are not arrays themselves. Maybe the pointer(s) themselves on the stack were overwritten and corrupted.

Comment: @PhilPerry: Yes, `str`, `str1`, and `str2` are arrays, not, I repeat not, pointers. There are no pointer objects in the code in the question. They do not point to anything; they contain (read/write) character sequences. `char str[] = "dance";` is equivalent to `char str[6] = "dance";`

Comment: str, str1, and str2 _are_ technically pointers, pointing to the first character of each string. They are on the stack in read-write memory. The three strings (text + \0) could be in read-only memory, as fixed text strings are not supposed to be altered. This particular compiler might have put them on the stack or in the heap. In any case, str1 doesn't have enough space to add the text from str2, which could cause almost anything to go wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`str1` has not enough space to concatenate the string `str2`. This invokes **undefined behavior**. You may get anything. Either expected or unexpected result.
Now try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(void) {
    char str[]="dance";
    char str1[10]="hello";
    char str2[]="abcd";
    strcat(str1,str2);
    printf("%s\n",str1);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
helloabcd
dance
```

Comment: And what's most likely happening in this case is that `str` is allocated in memory immediately after `str1`. The `strcat` call writes past the end of `str1`, clobbering `str`. This is not the only possible behavior; it's just what you (the OP) happen to get in this particular case.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Now it will not :).

Answer (score 2):

#### I got it...

as I have not given the size of `str1` , both `str1` and `str` are present in the memory one after another

like

```
h e l l o \0 d a n c e
```

so when I concatenate `str1` and `str2` following thing happens...

```
a replaces \0
b replaces d
c replaces a
d replaces n
\0 replaces c
```

and hence `str` is altered

Comment: Yes but remember this is not a defined behavior in C.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : its true ...I can not rely on this fact...it is different in different computers

Comment: In-fact can be different on different execution instances!!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan :ya it is also possible , but I have tried it many times...still got same result

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : just out of curiosity I want to tell you that I am also from Delhi

Comment: Yes It is possible but still under undefined behavior. Because you are getting stack-memory you can disassemble your executable and learn how it works at low-level.

Comment: You cannot count on where the three **Read Only** text strings are in memory, or relative to one another, so your explanation is not correct _in general_. This is simply the behavior of this one compiler.

Comment: @PhilPerry : ya it is just a coincidence with my machine....
my explanation is also for this case only

Comment: @learner nice then you should be happy because you are living in second New York    ;)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : I am a first year student of Galgotias college of engg. and tech. gr Noida...
you must be aware of it

Comment: @learner  Good!... you can find my personal email @ my profile page.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : maybe its too early , but still I want to remain in contact with you as I have just started my career with great enthusiasm and hope to get selected in good company

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45832/discussion-between-learner-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : I want to talk to you little bit...in chat

Answer (score 0):

This is a "Undefined behavior"

`str`, `str1`, `str2` have a limited size, and they are putted in the stack, the sequence depends on the compiler. You probably have something like this in your stack.

`['a']['b']['c']['d']['\0']['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']['\0']['d']['a']['n']['c']['e']['\0']`

Got it?

When you writes after the initial size of `str1`, you are overriding the stack, an changing all others variable that are on the stack.

Comment: Wrong. Only the 3 pointers str, str1, and str2 are on the stack (roughly 4 bytes each). The three character arrays they point to are off somewhere else, possibly in read-only memory (fixed content, not to be altered). _Where_ they are, and in what relation to each other, is beyond your control. The point still holds in that str1 is not long enough (even if you _could_ write to it) to hold the extra text being added.

Comment: there is no pointer, only arrays, they are initialized side by side at the stack, possibly with padding.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating `str2` to `str1`, but `str1` is not big enough to hold both strings. There is a buffer overflow that corrupts the contents of the third string on the stack, `str`.

When you define

```
char str1[] = "hello";
```

you create an array of six chars, 5 for "hello" plus one null character to terminate the string. The string is already full, so to speak. A quick fix is to specify an array size:

```
char str1[20] = "hello";
```

Now you should be able to append `str2` to `str1` with `strcat`.

In practice, you should ensure that the buffer is big enough to hold the whole string:

```
char buf[20];

if (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) < 20) {
    strcpy(buf, str1);
    strcat(buf, str2);
}
```

This is tedious. There is another way to concatenate strings without buffer overflow:

```
char buf[20];
int n;

n = snprintf(buf, 20, "%s%s", str1, str2);
```

This might cut the whole string short, but will not overflow the buffer. The return value `n` tells how many characters would have been written, had there been enough space, so you can use it to check.